# configBuilder 'Secrets' failed

Tags: azure, publish

After the initial attempt to publish my web app to Azure I got the following error. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

1. Is there a way to undo the publish?
2. How do I determine what is missing?

The configBuilder 'Secrets' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'.: 'Secrets' Initialization Error: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Utils.MapPath(System.String)'.

Comment: Could you add code in your question for better understanding?

Comment: this is the actual error. Line 18:  
Line 19:  
Line 20:   <appSettings configBuilders="Secrets">
Line 21:     <add key="owin:appStartup" 
   value="AccManager.Startup" />
Line 22:     <add key="ChartImageHandler" 
   value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />

Source File: C:\Web Directory\ActivityManager\AccManager\web.config    Line: 20  not sure what code I could include that wouldbe helpful. The question is how do I undo the chanhes that Publish did within my projecy?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I undo the changes that Publish did within my project:

***Approach-1:-***

Generally, Azure Web Apps provides [back up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup?tabs=portal#restore-a-backup) feature which you may enable in your app to keep a backup of your site. If you are sure that the deployment did not go as planned, you can restore the backup.

- Goto `App Service -> Choose BackUps`
  You can see the status of the webapps for every hour as shown here:

[image]

- Click on Restore icon if needed.
- Enter the restore location in Choose a location. Select Create new under the App Service box to restore to a new app. Select Create new beneath the Deployment slot box to restore to a new deployment slot.
- You can choose the site configuration as well as per requirements. After providing all these, restore it.

[image]

***Approach-2:-***

- Usually after publishing any web app to azure from local, it will be deployed on production server.
- You may want to undertake some activity or verification before delivering/after delivering the website to production. You can use deployment slots in this case.
- Azure provides non-production deployment slots for each web app, on which we can deploy the website temporarily.
  Detailed in [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-webapp-rollback-your-deployment-using-deployment-slot/) given by @Krishna Kumar.

*Create deployment slot by adding a slot under app service as shown*:

[image]

Alternative Reference: [Get publish profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/how-to-get-publish-profile-from-azure-app-service?view=vs-2022)

Comment: sorry it's taken so long getting back to this. FLU. Lots of good info. Thanks. Still trying to figure out why "Publish" broke my app on my local machine. It appears that it has something to do with setup  Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Fine. Check your [config builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder) following the correct syntax. This may be helpful.